# Can't print a Random integer

Tags: java

I have just started learning Java. I was learning about "Randomization" from the "Kilobolt" tutorials. When I ran this code:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Randomization {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.nextInt(11);
        System.out.println(rand);
    }
}
```

The console displayed:

> java.util.Random@1888759

Is this supposed to happen? Or are there errors in my code?

( Sorry if i used any wrong terms in this question, I'm new to the website)

Comment: You need to store somewhere the result of `nextInt` (or directly print it). So `int random = rand.nextInt(11); System.out.println(random);`

Comment: You are trying to print memory address of random object.

Comment: This is supposed to happen. rand is a reference to a Random object. When you println(rand), the toString() of Object is called and gives you the output you get.

Comment: @Mingyu No, the default `Object#toString()` implementation is not the memory address of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing a reference to the object `rand`. You can either print out the random number like below:

```
public class Randomization {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt(11));
    }
}
```

Or you can store it in an int before printing:

```
public class Randomization {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(11);
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
    }
}
```

Either should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
public class Randomization {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(11);
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
  }
}
```

Because you need to print the `number`. not the `object` of `Random`.

Answer (score 2):

you are printing the object         `System.out.println(rand);`
 so you are getting this `java.util.Random@1888759`

try this way

```
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(11));
```

[Full working code](http://ideone.com/ZoxTTO)

Answer (score 2):

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

this variable has been declared as a Object of Random.
however I'm pretty sure your intentions were to show the number that will be produced randomly.
To show it as a number, you have to declare the variable as an object of int.
to do that you can do :

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(11);
```

hope this helps.